# How are key-value pairs stored in redis?

Tags: redis

Suppose in redis, there are the following key-value pairs of type string :
key1 val1
key2 val2
I know that they are stored internally in table.

**Are these key-value pairs stored in one single table? 
or are there different tables for each key-value pair?**

i.e., does only a single table contain both the key-value pairs or does one table store key1-val1 and another table store key2-val2?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is only one single table for all key-value pairs in the same Redis DB.

Actually, key-value pair is stored in a big hash table.

https://github.com/antirez/redis/blob/unstable/src/redis.h#L469

```
/* Redis database representation. There are multiple databases identified
* by integers from 0 (the default database) up to the max configured
* database. The database number is the 'id' field in the structure. */
typedef struct redisDb {
    dict *dict;                 /* The keyspace for this DB */
    dict *expires;              /* Timeout of keys with a timeout set */
    dict *blocking_keys;        /* Keys with clients waiting for data (BLPOP) */
    dict *ready_keys;           /* Blocked keys that received a PUSH */
    dict *watched_keys;         /* WATCHED keys for MULTI/EXEC CAS */
    struct evictionPoolEntry *eviction_pool;    /* Eviction pool of keys */
    int id;                     /* Database ID */
    long long avg_ttl;          /* Average TTL, just for stats */
} redisDb;
```

All key-value pairs are stored in dict.